# How to prevent .dfm files from breaking string values from middle of words?

Tags: delphi, full-text-search, delphi-2010, dfm

I was searching for name of a table in all .pas and .dfm files of my project using [Grep Search](http://www.gexperts.org/tour/index.html?grep_search.html). It only could find results in .pas files, while I was sure that there was at least one dataset that use this table. I searched the name of dataset in .dfm file and this is what I found:

```
  object DtsRPCondition: TADODataSet
    Connection = ConnMain
    CursorType = ctStatic
    CommandText = 
      'select FromDay, ToDay, ToTime, Daily, DayOfWeek from Tbl_Reserve' +
      'ValidDay'
   ...
```

This makes it useless to search through .dfm files, so I need either an option that controls writing .dfm files or another search tool that can handle this.

Comment: DFMs saved as Text will break strings at fixed lengths regardless of content, nothing you can do about that. DFMs saved as Binary do not do that.

Comment: It is unlikely that EMBT would change the formatting of `.dfm` files. Maybe you need to consider writing text, that you may need to search for, in code (in `.pas` file), so you can format it as search friendly as you wish.

Comment: Delphi will only break such strings into multiple lines which it deems too long. Simple workaround is to add line breaks yourself. If you add one before `from` grep should start to work for you.

Comment: In case that wasn't clear: I don't meant you to edit the DFM file but to properly format things like the `CommandText` property during development. Makes it also easier to read SVN diffs and such.

Comment: @TomBrunberg there's nothing that I can do about it, it's an old project with not even a single paper of docs. I have to discover the design before I fixing bugs.

Comment: And to closure voters: which stack site is the proper one for such question?

Comment: I understand your dilemma, but your question can only be answered as @RemyLebeau already did. `.dfm` files in binary format doesn't break the lines, but is difficult to use in other ways.

Comment: I was about to suggest using GExperts Grep, but unfortunately it doesn't find such strings either. Maybe you could create a feature request on that? https://sourceforge.net/p/gexperts/feature-requests

Comment: It would be a fairly trivial task to write your own tool to convert dfm files to a searchable format (obviously not overwriting the original file) by recombining the lines.

Comment: @mjn42 when was that? And who answered? (Who is "they"?)

Comment: Considering that grep seems to accept regular expression, you can build a regular expression that can match your table even when it's splitten in different lines : T(' + \n ')*b*(' + \n ')l(' + \n ')*_(' + \n ')*R(' + \n ')*e(' + \n ')*s(' + \n ')* ... .... ....

Comment: @MarcGuillot "grep seems to accept regular expressions"? That's the reason for its existence. It's a regular expression pattern matcher. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grep

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, now that you put it this way the name becomes obvious :-)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan does grep search allow searching regular expressions in more than one line? I tried `\n`, `\f`, `\r` and their combinations, but it doesn't match anything after them.

Comment: Do a websearch to find the answer to that. None of these questions are new. The existence of Stack Overflow does not mean that you never do your own research.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan how did you come to this conclusion that I haven't done my own research?! I'm sure that you know re-asking an answered question does not mean that the questioner haven't done a websearch. btw, thanks for the tip..

Comment: A trivial search for multiline and grep would answer the question you asked in that comment. Clearly you asked without doing any research. You can get cross with me, and ignore me if you like. But if you'd like to get better, you'd heed the advice.

Comment: Anyone knows what will happen if I unwrap the strings in a DFM file? Will the IDE accept long (like 500 chars) strings. Does it has a (documented) limit?

Answer (score 2):

You could convert the dfm files to binary, without overwriting the text dfm files using the Convert utility bundled with Delphi:

```
convert -b -s -ebin *.dfm
```

Where `-b` = binary output, `-ebin` means use bin (or whatever else you want) as the extension for the new files, and -s means recurse subdirectories.

This will create a "bin" file for eash DFM. As noted above, there will be no word wrapping in these. While they are binary they should be grepable, and can be used to identify which DFM's you need to look at.

Comment: Some people like to close questions. Other people (like you) do actually answer them. Thanks!